# Setting up a dependent and auto-updating repo with git

Tags: git, github, repository, github-actions

I'm new to git so I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

There is a repo that I want to add files too and I want those added files to interact with existing files on the repo. Additionally, I'd want my own files to run and update whenever there are changes to the existing repo.

I'm not really sure how I should go about this, such as making my own entirely new repo or if a clone or remote repo would be better, so I wanted to ask before wasting a bunch of time and making mistakes.

---

I'm not sure if my explanation makes sense so below is a graphic-ish representation:

```
                                        Repo A - not mine
                                               |
                                               v
                     Repo B? - Add a single python file which reads files 
                     from Repo A and then creates a couple new text files
                                               |
                                               v
                                      Repo A Updates a File(s)
                                               |
                                               v
               Repo B's python file will automatically run and update the text files
```

---

I hope that makes sense, if anyone has idea or suggestions I'd be happy to hear them.

Comment: Have you checked out `git submodule`? There's some limitations (such as the linked repo needing to be its own subdirectory), but I think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: @imbuedHope I saw that ealier but incorrectly thought I needed Repo B to be inside Repo A. I think this will work since I can also use `git submodule update --recursive` so it keeps Repo A up to date. Thanks for the recommendation, I wouldn't have looked back into submodules otherwise.

Comment: Note that a repository contains *commits* (not files). The commits then contain files, but it's a two-step process: get commits, use commits to get files. Each file has a *full snapshot of every commit* (frozen into the commit as a permanent archive).